# Perl - error trying to access array stored as hash value

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, bioinformatics

I'm running into a problem with a small portion of a bigger script. I'm trying to store file names in an array as the value of a hash so as to be able to list them all later. Below is the loop in which I build the hash %extramapped:

```
for (my $i=0; $i<scalar(@refgenomes); $i++) {
            my $extraRefPath = $refgenomes[$i];
            my @extraFieldRef = split("/", $extraRefPath);
            my @extraFullRefName = split("\\.", $extraFieldRef[-1]);
            my $extraRefName = $extraFullRefName[0];
            my $extraTempOutFile = $gzFile.$extraRefName.".sort.bam";
            my $extraCmd = "$bwa bam2bam -n 0.01 -o 2 -l 16500 -g $extraRefPath <($fixpair -o /dev/stdout $tempOutFile) | samtools sort -o /dev/stdin ".$gzFile.".sort"." >$extraTempOutFile";
            push(@listTargets, $extraTempOutFile);
            push(@{$extramapped{$extraRefName}}, $extraTempOutFile);
            $stringMakeToPrint = $stringMakeToPrint.$extraTempOutFile.": ".$tempOutFile."\n\t$extraCmd\n\n";
```

When I check the contents of the hash with Data::Dumper, it looks as I would expect:

>

```
 $VAR1 = {
>           'rCRS' => [
> '..//Sample_LP30/LP30_CCTAGGT-ACCTAGG_L001_R1_001.fastq.gzrCRS.sort.bam',
> '..//Sample_LP30/LP30_CCTAGGT-ACCTAGG_L001_R1_002.fastq.gzrCRS.sort.bam',
> '..//Sample_LP30/LP30_CCTAGGT-ACCTAGG_L001_R1_003.fastq.gzrCRS.sort.bam',
> '..//Sample_LP30/LP30_CCTAGGT-ACCTAGG_L002_R1_001.fastq.gzrCRS.sort.bam',
> '..//Sample_LP30/LP30_CCTAGGT-ACCTAGG_L002_R1_002.fastq.gzrCRS.sort.bam',
> '..//Sample_LP30/LP30_CCTAGGT-ACCTAGG_L002_R1_003.fastq.gzrCRS.sort.bam'
>                     ],
>           'Copy_NC' => [
> '..//Sample_LP30/LP30_CCTAGGT-ACCTAGG_L001_R1_001.fastq.gzCopy_NC.sort.bam',
> '..//Sample_LP30/LP30_CCTAGGT-ACCTAGG_L001_R1_002.fastq.gzCopy_NC.sort.bam',
> '..//Sample_LP30/LP30_CCTAGGT-ACCTAGG_L001_R1_003.fastq.gzCopy_NC.sort.bam',
> '..//Sample_LP30/LP30_CCTAGGT-ACCTAGG_L002_R1_001.fastq.gzCopy_NC.sort.bam',
> '..//Sample_LP30/LP30_CCTAGGT-ACCTAGG_L002_R1_002.fastq.gzCopy_NC.sort.bam',
> '..//Sample_LP30/LP30_CCTAGGT-ACCTAGG_L002_R1_003.fastq.gzCopy_NC.sort.bam'
>                        ]
>         };
```

However, I'm having a hard time getting those file names to come back out. I though I could do it with join(" ", @{$extramapped{$extraRefName}}), however it isn't behaving as I would expect. When I simply ask it to print the list as such:

```
my $extraFileList = join(" ", @{$extramapped{$extraRefName}});
print "This is the extra file list $extraFileList\n";
```

I get the expected list:

```
> This is the extra file list ..//Sample_LP32/LP32_GCTCGAA-ACTTCAA_L001_R1_001.fastq.gzCopy_NC.sort.bam ..//Sample_LP32/LP32_GCTCGAA-ACTTCAA_L001_R1_002.fastq.gzCopy_NC.sort.bam ..//Sample_LP32/LP32_GCTCGAA-ACTTCAA_L002_R1_001.fastq.gzCopy_NC.sort.bam ..//Sample_LP32/LP32_GCTCGAA-ACTTCAA_L002_R1_002.fastq.gzCopy_NC.sort.bam
```

but when I try and incorporate it into a a loop like this:

```
for (my $i=0; $i<scalar(@refgenomes); $i++) {
    my $extraFileList = join(" ", @{$extramapped{$extraRefName}});
    my $extraMmfCmd = "$samtools merge $extraFileList | $retrieve /dev/stdin /dev/stdout | $rmdup -c -o $extraMapFileName /dev/stdin";
```

I get the following error and the loop dies.

```
> Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference at line 152.
```

I don't understand why the output is different in this case. Can anyone explain it to me? Suggest how to fix it?

Cheers,
Ana

Comment: Is it possible that $extramapped{$extraRefName} is out of scope at that point in the program?  (either %extramapped or $extraRefName)

Comment: I don't think that could be it as, when I put in the print statement to test, I placed it right above my $extraMmfCmd and it prints just fine.

Comment: You might try putting some more print statements directly after the start of the loop and before the "my $extraFileList..." part... like, print the value of $extraRefName and then print "ref $extramapped{$extraRefName}" (which should give you ARRAY, but it probably won't.  If it doesn't then try moving the print statement up a few lines before the loop and see if you get ARRAY there.

Comment: That was a great idea, thanks. I realised it was dying on 4th iteration through loop, checked and turned out that the 4th input violated the pattern and so it was trying to pass nothing into the array. It's working great now. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@{...}` *dereferences* an array reference. So if it's blowing up here:

```
my $extraFileList = join(" ", @{$extramapped{$extraRefName}});
```

then it is clearly a result of `$extramapped{$extraRefName}` not storing an array reference to dereference.

Either,

- `$extraRefName` no longer refers to a valid key
- or, `$extramapped{$extraRefName}` was deleted by something, somewhere else.

Some people have adopted the practice of avoiding this error, by *or-ing* it with an empty array reference: `@{ $hash{ $keyNotThere } || [] }`. Although, this tends to be a little wasteful in array creation. What you really want is a more cumbersome:

```
ref( $aref ) eq 'ARRAY' ? @$aref : ();
```

(Of course it could be the case that the Perl wizards have optimized the empty array dereference, already.)

Comment: As I mention above it response to ratsbane, the problem turned out to be the input not the script itself. Thanks for the explanation, I'll have to look into this ref eq ARRAY notation some more. Cheers.